# All ramifications of "Lo BaShamayim Hi"

Tags: halacha, hashkafah-philosophy, halacha-theory

What are all the ramifications of "Lo BaShamayim Hi"?

Comment: Practical ramifications? Philosophical ramifications?

Comment: @jake ALL! everything.

Comment: @HachamGabriel different people have different opinions. For example, the anti-kabalists like to argue that even if the Kabalah is all true, Lo BaShamayim Hi, and practical halacha should not follow the teachings of the Arizal.  Obviously, most Jews don't hold that way. So can you narrow down your question a bit?

Comment: When the gemara says Teku Eliyahu Hanavi wont be able to Poskin Halacha only tell us what the Metziyus is

Comment: Sha'alot U'teshuvot Min Hashamayim is not accepted Lhalcha

Comment: nor is Maggid Meisharim because of  "Lo BaShamayim He"

Comment: Good points (see Gevurat HaAri)

Comment: Should this be closed as too broad instead?

Answer (score 2):

Considering the generality of your question I think that most appropriate answer is the most general usage:

The Torah was given with some "wiggiling room" in specific circumstances (in secular law they call this being "given to interpretation"). Human beings were given certain prerogative - even if the outcome effects D'Oraysays. Lo Bashamim means that "we the people" have said prerogative and that we do not defer to heavenly signs for the "right" path.

For example: eating Chametz on Pesach is a D'Oraysa. Nevertheless, (at least in the times of the Beis Hamikdash) Beis Din had the power/prerogative to decide when Rosh Chodesh Nisan would be - thereby directly affecting which day will be the first day of Pesach. Now, while one can be concerned that Beis Din would cause all of k'lal yisroel to eat Chometz on (what could/should be) the first day of pesach, because of the power vested them, Hashem counts the BD's decision as fact - and only considers Rosh Chodesh (and by extension, Pesach) to be when BD decided it to be.

Another example is a story in the Gemora (see Bava Metzio 59b) where there was a dispute in the Beis Hamedrash and to prove their point one of the Amaoraim said "let the heavens testify that I'm correct" - and indeed a Bas Kol was heard saying that he is indded correct. However the Chahomim disqulifed this proof with "Lo Bashmayim Hi" and you can't pasken based on something heard (even directly from) Shomaim.

Comment: You already noted the source (BM 59b) for the dispute over the oven.  Is that "source needed" a stray comment, or are you looking for a link?

Comment: @MonicaCellio just as a reference I placed it there.