Sanhedrin power do redefine Hebrew language concepts (left and right)
The Torah forbids us from straying from Sanhedrin's rulings left or right (Deut 17.11). Left and right are abstract linguistic concepts that reflect certain social conventions. Needless to say, the Torah is full of situations that point to the use of right or left (like in "But Israel stretched out his right hand and laid it on Ephraim’s head, and his left hand on Manasseh’s head..." Gen 48.14).
Two Halachic approaches emerge:

Rabbis can NOT change basic concepts like left and right (Jer Horayot.1.1.7):


"יָכוֹל אִם יֹאמְרוּ לָךְ עַל יְמִין שֶׁהִיא שְׂמֹאל וְעַל שְׂמֹאל שֶׁהִיא יְמִין תִּשְׁמַע לָהֶם? תַּלְמוּד לוֹמַר לָלֶכֶת יָמִין וּשְׂמֹאל. שֶׁיֹּאמְרוּ לָךְ עַל יָמִין שֶׁהוּא יָמִין וְעַל שְׂמֹאל שֶׁהִיא שְׂמֹאל."
"One could think that if they say about right that it is left, and about left that it is right, he should listen to them? [Nonsense,] The verse says, “to go to the right or to the left;” [meaning only in the case] that they should tell you about the right that it is right, and about the left that it is left."


Rabbis can change basic concepts like left and right (Sifrei Devarim.154.5 and supported by Rashi):


"ימין ושמאל, אפילו מראים בעיניך על ימין שהוא שמאל ועל שמאל שהוא ימין שמע להם".
"right or left": Even if they show you that left is right and right is left, listen to them.

According to the latter, commonly accepted, approach, does it mean the Sanhedrin had the power to change the meaning of basic linguistic concepts? When "they show you that left is right and right is left", do they redefine those concepts and switch their meaning, like calling a cow a dog?
In general, can we say that the Rabbinic power (aka "Not in Heaven") extends even to redefining the Hebrew Language?

Or maybe they show you that what you think is left is actually, from another vantage point, right.

@rosends I don’t get it: I sit in the Sanhedrin with another 150 people, and the president says "I deem your left hand to be your right hand". What should all people present think?

On the apparent contradiction between the Yerushalmi and Sifrei see Ramban and Tora Temima there. But neither of them are talking about redefining words, it's a figure of speech (Ramban: וְעִנְיָנוֹ אֲפִלּוּ תַּחְשֹׁב בְּלִבְּךָ שֶׁהֵם טוֹעִים, וְהַדָּבָר פָּשׁוּט בְּעֵינֶיךָ כַּאֲשֶׁר אַתָּה יוֹדֵעַ בֵּין יְמִינְךָ לִשְׂמֹאלְךָ
)

@ba Ramban & TT make it figurative and personal "as if they tell you...". This is not what Yerushalmi says - "יָכוֹל אִם יֹאמְרוּ לָךְ עַל יְמִין שֶׁהִיא שְׂמֹאל וְעַל שְׂמֹאל שֶׁהִיא יְמִין תִּשְׁמַע לָהֶם.?" I.e. if they do so you have no obligation to listen. And this is exactly what I ask.


In general, can we say that the Rabbinic power (aka "Not in Heaven") extends even to redefining the Hebrew Language? If there was a known definition of a word  why were they even asked? How would that be a situation of  כִּ֣י יִפָּלֵא֩ מִמְּךָ֨ דָבָ֜ר לַמִּשְׁפָּ֗ט?


@Schmerel Think of amendments - e.g. what constitutes "speech". The Supreme Court might redefine the term to fit the digital age. Given "Not in Heaven", why can't Sanhedrin redefine basic terms, like "מעלה גרה" so the pig will become Kosher? Or gender to accommodate for the LGBT+++ BS. See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/104585/are-there-limitations-of-the-principle-not-in-heaven?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C50.7226

The certainly can not redefine basic terms, like "מעלה גרה"so the pig will become Kosher. If they could there would be no Par Heelam Dovor for when they made a mistake. Mistakes would be impossible. It would be their authority to redefine anything. If a new animal with unclear status is found they can decide if it is or isn't  "מעלה גרה". They can not change the status of a known forbidden one. See the first perek of Horayas for the rules

@Schmerel I don't understand how it works - we see the Achnai oven case where even God said they erred and they overruled it and banned R"E. When the Sanhedrin rules, it is final and there's no appeal. This is my understanding. I know Horayos but how does this "Sanhedrin errs" thing work?

In the Achnai oven case there was a legitimate prior question of what the Halacha. Under such circumstances of UNCLARITY  they have  the power to decide based on a set of pre existing rules what the halacha is. (Lo Bahamyim Hu is one of those rules. )In a situation where the Halacha is ALREADY KNOWN  they can't not redefine it and say  Lo Bahamyim Hu.

@Schmerel DIdn't God and R"E already know that? Achnai's case was a coup staged by R"G who paid for it with his life. I would suggest you reread the story and my questions about it and try to reconcile so nobody comes out stupid or ignorant.

You are badly distorting what happened so I will not respond further to you

@Schmerel I bet you didn't know that the whole story is brought up as an example of the severity of hurting a Talmid Chacham, and this is why R"G dies in the end. I would truly love to hear additional opinions that succeed in harmonizing the whole story from the beginning to the end.

This is from a friend's Facebook feed. It is too long for a comment but only addresses some of the question:

Neil Fleischmann


R Isser Zalman Meltzer notes that opposites can be conveyed as up & down, or as black & white, etc. Why choose right & left as the way we're meant to adhere to The Rabbis? Because my right is your left and vice versa.  We face the Chachamim and see it backwards because their right is our left!


Soon the phrase is repeated and the same drasha is not made - the king keeps a Torah and should not deviate from it right or left.  Similarly, Rav Isser Zalman's approach applies (as explained by Rav Daniel Feldman): he shouldn’t think he has G-d’s perspective, he's still a human and his perspective is reverse!


Micha Berger


As a lefty, I like the idea of strong-side vs weak-side. Halachic works even often specify that a lefty should do something with "his right hand", which is everyone else's left. E.g., (one of 133 in Sefaria's Halakhah section)
Shulchan Arukh OC 27:6 opens, "ואיטר יד ימינו אם עושה כל מלאכתו בשמאלו מניח בשמאלו שהוא ימין של כל אדם - A lefty who does all his work with his left hand puts his Tefillin on his 'left hand' which is the right hand of all people."
An important reminder these days especially:
Good is stronger than evil!


+1 Those are nice exegesis. However, the understanding of Yerushalmi is pretty straightforward. Similarly, Rashi implies that one must subdue due to their authority and despite common sense, not by simple reconciliation. Am I reading Rashi right?

Can you summarize the answer, in a form "it only seems contradicting"...

@AlBerko I think Rashi's point might include that "common" sense isn't always what we have in common.
